# PHP code for link with text

Tags: php, permalinks, links

I was exploring and ran across this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22423/grab-first-link-from-a-post-grab-first-blockquote

I would basically like to do the same thing, but have it call not only the URL but also the link, since I am using the link as an excerpt title.

For example; if my link is `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/>Facebook</a>` I want it to call a link that says `Facebook` not one that says `http://www.facebook.com` like the current code does.

This is probably easy when given the code provided already, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grab first link in post... and of course call it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16365/how-to-grab-first-link-in-post-and-of-course-call-it)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try with php [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) rather than regex. I don't think all DOMDocument methods will work with just an html fragment and not a complete document, but for your needs it may be enough:

```
<?php
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$html = '<p>Some html with a <a href="http://foo.com/">link</a>. Some more text and <a href="http://bar.com/">another</a> link.</p>';
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
foreach ( $elements as $element ){
    echo "link text: " . $element->nodeValue . "<br>";
    echo "href value: " . $element->getAttribute( 'href' ) . "<br><br>";
}

// outputs:
//
// link text: link
// href value: http://foo.com/
//
// link text: another
// href value: http://bar.com/
```

Comment: I don't get this, how would this pull from the post?  I don't want to manually input links.

Comment: I just put some dummy content in a variable as an example, `$html` would be whatever content you're passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually trying to do this too.

The following code calls up the link, but not like you're asking (with the actual text for the link included).  If you figure this out please post it and let us know, I could really use it!

```
function get_content_link( $content = false, $echo = false )
{
    // allows using this function also for excerpts
    if ( $content === false )
        $content = get_the_content(); // You could also use $GLOBALS['post']->post_content;

    $content = preg_match_all( '/href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']+)/', $content, $links );
    $content = $links[1][0];
    $content = make_clickable( $content );

    // if you set the 2nd arg to true, you'll echo the output, else just return for later usage
    if ( $echo === true )
        echo $content;

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured this sucker out. Use the code I provided above, put php the_title inside a link then make the src= point to the link created by the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a function that does something like this.

```
$partnersite = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>';
$partnersite = explode('>', $partnersite);
$partnersite = explode('<', $partnersite[1]);
echo $partnersite[0];
```